# How to make input data matrix in flowmapper

Tags: coordinates, contour, qgis-2.2, flow-map

I have problem with using flowmapper. I'm confused, how do I enter a text record? Can you give me an example of an appropriate text file?
I've been doing interpolation and made a contour of the ground water. How to create a flownet using flowmapper for my contour? This is my coordinate data:

[image]

[image]

Can you help me solve this problem?